# Заменить слово в листе Java

Tags: java, коллекции

я новичок и столкнулся с проблемой, хочу заменить определённые слова в List, но не выходит.

`Collections.replaceAll(list, "слово_1", "слово_2");`
Работает, но не так, как мне надо. Он заменяет слово только в том случае, если оно единственное что есть в строке, то есть если:

Входящая строка:

```
слово_1 другие слова
другие слова слово_1
слово_1
```

То вернётся:

```
слово_1 другие слова
другие слова слово_1
слово_2
```

Пробовал так же через цикл, но почему-то он игнорируется:

```
for(String s : list) {
    s.replaceAll("слово_1", "слово_2");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.StreamSupport;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("слово_1 другие слова");
        list.add("другие слова слово_1");
        list.add("слово_1");
        
        List<String> result = replace(list, "слово_1", "слово_2");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
    
    public static List<String> replace(Iterable<String> itrb, String from, String to) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(itrb.spliterator(), false)
                .map(line->line.replace(from, to))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    
}
```

Пишем специальный метод. Обратите внимание, что метод принимает Iterable - интерфейс, предоставляющий нам возможность передавать в аргументы при его вызове не только лист, но и любую другую коллекцию.
Кроме того, в данном случае лучше использовать метод replace, а не replaceAll. Причина в том, что последний использует регулярные выражения, в связи с чем работает медленнее.